# What is the zsh builtin `r` command for?

Tags: zsh

I accidentally typed `r` into the shell and got what appeared to be a repeat of the last command I ran.

`man zshbuiltins`, unhelpfully, [says](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-r) this:

> `r` - Same as `fc -e -`.

The documentation for `fc` [is almost impenetrable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc) but I managed to tease out these quotes:

- > `fc [ -e`*`ename`*`] [ -LI ] [ -m`*`match`*`] [`*`old=new`*`... ] [`*`first`*`[`*`last`*`] ]`
- > the editor program *ename* is invoked on a file containing these history events....When editing is complete, the edited command is executed.
- > If *ename* is `-`, no editor is invoked.

This reads to me like the behavior of `r` is similar to exclamation point `!`, in that it replays history. Indeed, if I `setopt banghist` to turn bang back on, things like `r man` and `! man` both seem to replay my last call to man.

What are the similarities and differences between `r` and `!`? What's a hypothetical scenario in which I could use `r`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have done a good job quoting the right passages from the man page.

*zsh* inherited `r` from *ksh*, as neither *bash* or *csh* know this command. I suppose the implementation is done to be as compatible as possible with these three major shells.

On the other hand the history bang mechanism `!` originates from *csh* which can be disabled with `setopt NO_BANG_HIST`.

One difference between these two mechanisms which comes to my mind is that `r` and `!` are parsed differently, as `!` is a reserved word but `r` only a (builtin) command. That means you can write e.g.

```
$ echo my last command was !!
```

which gets (depending on your settings after pressing `SPACE` or `ENTER`) to

```
$ echo my last command was man zshexpn
```

which isn't possible with `r` unless you use command substitution `$(r)` of course.

So, I thinks it all just boils down to personal preferences or habits (if you used to used *ksh* or *csh*)...